# My function is not called after a postback in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, webforms

I have a function called SetActionSection() which i placed in my pageload. I'm expecting it to be called but nothing happens. I get the result I want when I reload the page.

Here's the my pageload

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string fullName = GetUserFullName();
            string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
            TextBoxProjectManager.Text = fullName;

            if (id != null)
            {
                GetCMMDetails(TextBoxProjectManager.Text);

                int valid = ValidateUserAccess(id, fullName);
                if (valid > 0)
                    GetProjectPostEval();
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("You are not allowed to access this data.");
                    ActionSection.Visible = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TextBoxProjectManager.Text = fullName;
                GetCMMDetails(fullName);
            }
            SetActionSection();
        }

    }
```

Here is SetActionSection() function which shows the a button based on the status in the database.

```
private void SetActionSection()
    {
        string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
        if (id == null)
        {
            LinkButtonSaveDraft.Visible = true;
            LinkButtonSubmit.Visible = true;
            ActionSection.Visible = true;
            return;
        }
        string status = GetStatus(id);
        string projectManager = GetCMM(id, "ProjectManager");
        string buco = GetCMM(id, "Buco");
        string businessExecutiveOfficer = GetCMM(id, "BusinessExecutiveOfficer");
        string i2lFunctionLead = GetCMM(id, "I2LFunctionLead");
        string user = GetUserFullName();

        if ((status.Equals("Draft", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
           && user.Equals(projectManager, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            Response.Write(status + " Draft");
            LinkButtonSaveDraft.Visible = true;
            LinkButtonSubmit.Visible = true;
            ActionSection.Visible = true;
        }

        if (status.Equals("Submitted", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
             user.Equals(buco))
        {
            Response.Write(status + " Submitted");
            LinkButtonSaveDraft.Visible = false;
            LinkButtonSubmit.Visible = false;
            LinkButtonBUCOApprove.Visible = true;
            ActionSection.Visible = true;
        }

        if (status.Equals("(Approved) - BUCO", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            user.Equals(businessExecutiveOfficer))
        {
            Response.Write(status + " (Approved) - BUCO");
            LinkButtonBUCOApprove.Visible = false;
            LinkButtonBEOApprove.Visible = true;
        }

        if (status.Equals("(Approved) - BEO", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            user.Equals(businessExecutiveOfficer))
        {
            Response.Write(status + " (Approved) - BEO");
            LinkButtonBEOApprove.Visible = false;
            LinkButtonI2LFunctionLeadApprove.Visible = true;
        }
        if (status.Equals("(Approved) - I2L Function Lead", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            Response.Write(status + " (Approved) - I2L Function Lead");
            LinkButtonI2LFunctionLeadApprove.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

I have tested the SetActionSection method and it works. I just want it to be called when the user clicks the submit button. By the way. I'm redirecting to the same form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything inside your  if(!IsPostBack) condition will only be executed on initial load and not on submit. You could put the code you want to run on submit (postback) inside an else if you want

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
 {
 ....
 }
 else
 {
  SetActionSection();
 }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.ispostback?view=netframework-4.8

Or put your code inside a button click event